# Error parsing XSD schema : Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb2

I am getting an exception when parsing xsd file.
[image]

But the file itself is a valid xml file :
[image]

jaxb2-maven-plugin v 1.6

maven 3.3.9

Here is a part of that file (can't provide the whole file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ctns="http://some_address"
    xmlns:atns="http://some_address"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://some_address/article"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
```

And this is a stacktrace I can see when run `mvn clean install`

```
[INFO] parsing a schema...
[ERROR] file:/some_path/src/main/resources/META-INF/mySchema.xsd[1,1]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/some_path/src/main/resources/META-INF/mySchema.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:999)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2279)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:560)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:575)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:541)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:252)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:109)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:360)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:333)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Failed to parse a schema.
```

No special characters or anything else. What can it be ?

Comment: Post the stack trace and the XML file as a code block, not as an image.

Comment: You are using Windows, right? Because of the position of the error (`lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;`) I suspect you have been tricked by Microsoft. Have a look at your XML files - using a non Windows system may be helpful. My bet: the first bytes are a so called BOM - a "byte order mark". A violation to many standard file formats used on Microsoft systems. The BOM is completely useless if you are using UTF-8 and can be removed without causing problems.

Comment: @blafasel yes, windows, but I've checked the files in hex editor. there are no redundant characters

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue "Content is not allowed in prolog".
The issue was in the folder structure which contained special character.
Try to run in the project via cmd at a new  location with "mvnw clean compile".
It will definitely work.